# How to remove border radius from TextButton flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter, and I'm having this problem where my `TextButton` has a little border radius. Does anyone know how to remove the border radius from a `TextButton`?

My output

[image: app output]

My Code sorry for not including earlier
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrS5E.png)

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet that is producing this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added a picture of my code

Comment: @Logic kindly accept the answer if it did answer your question :) Thanks

Answer (score 18):

You can add a **shape** parameter to your **TextButton**

```
TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero))),
      child: const Text("BUtton"),
      onPressed: () {},
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code to your TextButton()

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
            ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Improving a bit from Danny Rufus' answer, you can use `BorderRadius.zero` to set the border radius to 0 for all corners

```
TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
          )
      ),
      child: const Text("Button"),
      onPressed: () {},
    )
```

or you could remove the `borderRadius` param since the default is `BorderRadius.zero` as seen on the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html#constructors)

so you can directly use `const RoundedRectangleBorder()`